# Is it possible to use Cucumber to test an existing Rails Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber

I have just finished reading many different web pages on the subject of Cucumber. It appears to be impossible to use Cucumber to test an existing Ruby on Rails application.  I'm just asking in case I missed something. (We are considering using it for future RoR app development.)

While I am asking, what is the current consensus on the best tool to test an existing Ruby on Rails application?

I did a little exploration with WATIR and it seems easy to use, but driving the web browser results in being not scalable. I have read some have moved from WATIR to Celerity....

However, I am in an environment where we are starting from zero previous testing. What is the 'best' choice to quickly write tests for an existing Ruby on Rails application?

Comment: Were you asking if you could use it with capybara to step through somebody else's deployed site? Because I'm looking to do something similar... just as a way to practice writing tests with fewer distractions...

Answer (score 3):

In no way is Cucumber unable to test an existing application. Not sure what gave you this idea, but perhaps because it's typically used with test-driven development?

Cucumber is by far the most widely used integration testing software for Rails. I would definitely suggest using Cucumber with Capybara, Guard, Spork, and RSpec for your testing suite. (RSpec for unit testing, Capybara for integration tests, Guard and Spork for running your tests quickly).

If you've never looked at Cucumber before, you might want to take a look at some [tutorials](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/tutorials-and-related-blog-posts) first.

To get started on your project, try to make a Cucumber feature for a simple feature. For example, write a test to visit the homepage. Something like:

```
Feature: View homepage
   Given I am on the profile page
   When I click "home"
   Then I should see the homepage logo
```

Once you've understood that, move on to more complicated features. Examples might include create a user account, login, view a profile, etc. (I don't know what your application does but I think you get the point.)

Comment: Each and every document (website) I have read in the past 2 days indicates the application is developed in conjunction with cucumber testing as you create the application. Now I am wondering if the word -unable- in the first line of your response should have been -able-, changing the meaning to "In no way is Cucumber able to test an existing application". Please confirm the content of your reply to my question.

Comment: If I were to start testing thousands of lines of existing Ruby/Rails code, I would first have to study at great length to determine the various scenarios required to test the code. Reverse engineering the scenarios.  It seems like that would take FAR more time than to simply validate the continuing proper function using something like WATIR or Celerity.

Comment: No, I meant unable. Cucumber is able to test an existing application. (Apologies for the double negative.)

Comment: I don't understand your second comment. If you're learning a testing suite, you're going to have to learn it whether you make a new application or put tests into an old one. I've done both, and in fact I learned by putting existing tests into an old one. Furthermore, Cucumber may be built for TDD/BDD, but you can use it for test-after development as well. Many people do this.

Comment: To expand on my comment.  Without really knowing all the details of the code behind the web form, I could create automated tests (with WATIR or Celerity) that would detect failures in the function of the application after changes were made.  To use Cucumber, based on what I have read so far, I have to write scenarios which would require a detailed understanding of the code within the application.

Comment: Not really. Cucumber defines steps (as shown above), and then you write code to check that those steps work as step definitions. For example, to test if a user sign in was working, in the step definitions, you would create a user, navigate to the sign in form, fill in the form, click submit, and check you're on the right page. How the code works that handles sign in is behind the scenes and unrelated to the Cucumber code (or RSpec/Capybara, more accurately).

Comment: OK, so you appear to be saying Cucumber can be used to develop a headless web browser test driving application. I have yet to find an article (on the internet) which discusses developing such an app with Cucumber. All the articles I am reading appear to be discussing creating of web applications from ground zero. Hence my original question.  If you happen to know of a link to an article showing Cucumber being used to develop a headless browser test, I would appreciate receiving the link.  Thank you, ~ Allen

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what Cucumber is: basically a way to organize your testing. It seems like you're looking for something like Capybara (https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) to compare WATIR and Celerity. You can use Cucumber in conjunction with Capybara.. But Cucumber is a faaaar different tool from WATIR or Celerity (at least it appears that way from reading their documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber is able to test an existing application.

You have to set configuration setting for cucumber and generate cucumber folder by rails g cucumber

before run this command you have to include gem: gem 'cucumber'.